# Get audio playing speed android

Tags: android, audio, visualizer

let me describe my situation. I'm developing a music visualizer for android. thank to Visualizer class, i can get the waveform and fft data to visualize as graphic on the screen. Now i want something more, the speed of the effect must base on the mood/speed of current playing audio (ie: "romance" is slow, "wakawaka" is fast), I've spent a whole day for searching but got no ideas, please help me

Comment: So you want BPM, not a multiplier of the original speed? Getting the BPM is beyond the scope of any built-in functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure, I just need to know if the playing melody is fast or slow at the moment so i can draw more wave and vice versa. Any suggestion, i'm stuck :(